# Chapter and verse numbers in Greek vs Hebrew/Aramaic

Tags: septuagint, bible-versions, peshitta

What differences in chapter and verse numbers are between Greek and Hebrew/Aramaic?

For instance [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Hosea%201#en-NIV-22106), differences are scattered in footnotes of each chapter.

Where to find a list of all differences in one place?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic because it is looking for a list, and that's not a good fit for this format.

Comment: @JackDouglas Where is the right place to ask this question?

Comment: I'd start [with Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible) and follow the references - apart from that, I'm afraid I don't know, this is the only site I know well.

Comment: TN. Did you meant Hebrew vs Greek?  If you meant Aramaic, is your question in regard to Aramaic portions of the OT or to the Aramaic Peshitta/Peshitto?  If the latter, you might try asking in the forum at Peshitta.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the differences between the Hebrew/Aramaic Old Testament and the LXX are in a helpful pdf (of Appendix E from SBL's Handbook of Style) which a person named Denise has posted on this page: http://community.logos.com/forums/p/67596/470753.aspx